# Second Accordion Panel not updating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the accordian I made the first panel is an icon selection. After one of the icons is selected it replaces the second accordion panel with one of three panels depending on which icon is selected. I think my problem lies with the javascript and how i set it up. I think my problem may also lie within the div.panel class in the class.

HTML

```
<button class="accordion">
                    <h2 class="float-left">1.</h2>
                    <h2 class="text-center">Screen Type</h2></button> 
                <div class="panel text-center" id="type_panel">
                    <label class="icon-select">
                        <input type="radio" name="type" id="laptop_button" /> <img src="icons/iconmonstr-laptop-4-120.png" alt="laptop"> </label>
                    <label class="icon-select">
                        <input type="radio" name="type" id="tablet_button" /> <img src="icons/iconmonstr-tablet-1-120.png" alt="tablet"> </label>
                    <label class="icon-select">
                        <input type="radio" name="type" id="phone_button" /> <img src="icons/iconmonstr-smartphone-3-120.png" alt="phone"> </label>
                </div>
                <form action="" id="tallyForm" onsubmit="return false;">
                    <button class="accordion">
                        <h2 class="float-left">2.</h2>
                        <h2 class="text-center">Model</h2></button>
                    <div class="panel" id="default_panel">
                        <label><h3 class="text-center">Please select a Device Type above</h3></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel invisible" id="laptop_panel">
                        <div id="col1">
                            <label class="control control--radio">LAPTOP
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="laptop1" />
                                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="col3">
                            <label class="control control--radio">LAPTOP2
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="laptop2" />
                                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="col2">
                            <label class="control control--radio">LAPTOP3
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="laptop3" />
                                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel invisible" id="tablet_panel">
                        <div id="col1">
                            <label class="control control--radio">iPad 2
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="tablet-ipad2" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
                                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                            <label class="control control--radio">iPad 3
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="tablet-ipad3" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
                                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                            <label class="control control--radio">iPad 4
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="tablet-ipad4" />
                                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                            <label class="control control--radio">iPad Air
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="tablet-ipadAir" />
                                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                            <label class="control control--radio">iPad Mini
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="tablet-ipadMini" />
                                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                            <label class="control control--radio">iPad Mini 2
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="tablet-ipadMini2" />
                                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="col3">
                            <label class="control control--radio">Nexus 7
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="tablet-nexus7" />
                                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="col2">
                            <label class="control control--radio">Amazon Fire
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="tablet-amazonFire" />
                                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                            <label class="control control--radio">Amazon Kindle
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="tablet-amazonFire" />
                                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel invisible" id="phone_panel">
                        <div id="col1">
                            <label class="control control--radio">iPhone 3 &amp; 4
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="phone-iphone3" />
                                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                            <label class="control control--radio">iPhone 5, 5c, 5s
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="phone-iphone5cs" />
                                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                            <label class="control control--radio">iPhone 6
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="phone-iphone6" />
                                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                            <label class="control control--radio">iPhone 6 Plus
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="phone-iphone6+" />
                                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="col3">
                            <label class="control control--radio">Microsoft Lumia 430
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="phone-lumia430" />
                                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div id="col2">
                            <label class="control control--radio">Galaxy S3
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="phone-galaxys3" />
                                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                            <label class="control control--radio">Galaxy S4
                                <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="phone-galaxys4" />
                                <div class="control__indicator"></div>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

CSS

```
.icon-select {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#col1 {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    height: 100%;
}

#col2 {
    float: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 33%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table-cell;
}

#col3 {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 34%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: table-cell;
}

button.accordion {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 2px;
    width: 50%;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    transition: 0.4s;
    border-left: 1px solid #6fdd7a;
    border-right: 1px solid #6fdd7a;
    border-top: 1px solid #6fdd7a;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom: none;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #6fdd7a;
    color: #ffffff;
}

div.panel {
    padding: 0px 18px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 46%;
    border-right: 1px dotted #6fdd7a;
    border-left: 1px dotted #6fdd7a;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

#optional_panel {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #6fdd7a;
}

label > input {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
}

label > input + img {
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 2px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
}

label > input:checked + img {
    background-color: #6fdd7a;
}

.invisible {
    display: none;
}

.showing {
    padding: 0px 18px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    max-height: 600px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 46%;
    border-right: 1px dotted #6fdd7a;
    border-left: 1px dotted #6fdd7a;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
// JUST STYLES THE RADIO BUTTONS AND 
.control {
    font-size: 18px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.control input {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
}

.control__indicator {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    left: 0;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #e6e6e6;
}

.control--radio .control__indicator {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.control:hover input ~ .control__indicator,
.control input:focus ~ .control__indicator {
    background: #444;
}

.control input:checked ~ .control__indicator {
    background: #6fdd7a;
}

.control:hover input:not([disabled]):checked ~ .control__indicator,
.control input:checked:focus ~ .control__indicator {
    background: #6fdd7a;
}

.control__indicator:after {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    content: '';
}

.control input:checked ~ .control__indicator:after {
    display: block;
}

.control--checkbox .control__indicator:after {
    top: 4px;
    left: 8px;
    width: 3px;
    height: 8px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border: solid #fff;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

.control--checkbox input:disabled ~ .control__indicator:after {
    border-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.control--radio .control__indicator:after {
    top: 7px;
    left: 7px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #fff;
}

.control--radio input:disabled ~ .control__indicator:after {
    background: #7b7b7b;
}
```

JS

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function () {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
            panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        }
        else {
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        }
    };
}
$("#laptop_button").click(function () {
    $('#default_panel').addClass('invisible');
    $('#laptop_panel').removeClass('invisible');
    $('#laptop_panel').addClass('showing');
    $('#tablet_panel').addClass('invisible');
    $('#phone_panel').addClass('invisible');
});
$("#tablet_button").click(function () {
    $('#default_panel').addClass('invisible');
    $("#tablet_panel").removeClass('invisible');
    $('#tablet_panel').addClass('showing');
    $('#laptop_panel').addClass('invisible');
    $('#phone_panel').addClass('invisible');
});
$("#phone_button").click(function () {
    $('#default_panel').addClass('invisible');
    $("#phone_panel").removeClass('invisible');
    $('#phone_panel').addClass('showing');
    $('#laptop_panel').addClass('invisible');
    $('#tablet_panel').addClass('invisible');
});
```

JSFIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/jutmfuzc/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `max-height` on `.showing` since `div.panel` has `max-height: 0`

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  };
}
$("#laptop_button").click(function() {
  $('#default_panel').addClass('invisible');
  $('#laptop_panel').removeClass('invisible');
  $('#laptop_panel').addClass('showing');
  $('#tablet_panel').addClass('invisible');
  $('#phone_panel').addClass('invisible');
});
$("#tablet_button").click(function() {
  $('#default_panel').addClass('invisible');
  $("#tablet_panel").removeClass('invisible');
  $('#tablet_panel').addClass('showing');
  $('#laptop_panel').addClass('invisible');
  $('#phone_panel').addClass('invisible');
});
$("#phone_button").click(function() {
  $('#default_panel').addClass('invisible');
  $("#phone_panel").removeClass('invisible');
  $('#phone_panel').addClass('showing');
  $('#laptop_panel').addClass('invisible');
  $('#tablet_panel').addClass('invisible');
});
```

```css
.icon-select {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#col1 {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
}

#col2 {
  float: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 33%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table-cell;
}

#col3 {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  width: 34%;
  margin-left: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table-cell;
}

button.accordion {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 2px;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
  border-left: 1px solid #6fdd7a;
  border-right: 1px solid #6fdd7a;
  border-top: 1px solid #6fdd7a;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #6fdd7a;
  color: #ffffff;
}

div.panel {
  padding: 0px 18px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 46%;
  border-right: 1px dotted #6fdd7a;
  border-left: 1px dotted #6fdd7a;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

#optional_panel {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #6fdd7a;
}

label > input {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

label > input + img {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.25s linear;
}

label > input:checked + img {
  background-color: #6fdd7a;
}

.invisible {
  display: none;
}

div.showing {
  padding: 0px 18px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  max-height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 46%;
  max-height: 100%;
  border-right: 1px dotted #6fdd7a;
  border-left: 1px dotted #6fdd7a;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

// JUST STYLES THE RADIO BUTTONS AND 
.control {
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.control input {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
}

.control__indicator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 0;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #e6e6e6;
}

.control--radio .control__indicator {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.control:hover input ~ .control__indicator,
.control input:focus ~ .control__indicator {
  background: #444;
}

.control input:checked ~ .control__indicator {
  background: #6fdd7a;
}

.control:hover input:not([disabled]):checked ~ .control__indicator,
.control input:checked:focus ~ .control__indicator {
  background: #6fdd7a;
}

.control__indicator:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  content: '';
}

.control input:checked ~ .control__indicator:after {
  display: block;
}

.control--checkbox .control__indicator:after {
  top: 4px;
  left: 8px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 8px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border: solid #fff;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
}

.control--checkbox input:disabled ~ .control__indicator:after {
  border-color: #7b7b7b;
}

.control--radio .control__indicator:after {
  top: 7px;
  left: 7px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
}

.control--radio input:disabled ~ .control__indicator:after {
  background: #7b7b7b;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion">
  <h2 class="float-left">1.</h2>
  <h2 class="text-center">Screen Type</h2></button>
<div class="panel text-center" id="type_panel">
  <label class="icon-select">
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="laptop_button" /> <img src="icons/iconmonstr-laptop-4-120.png" alt="laptop"> </label>
  <label class="icon-select">
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="tablet_button" /> <img src="icons/iconmonstr-tablet-1-120.png" alt="tablet"> </label>
  <label class="icon-select">
    <input type="radio" name="type" id="phone_button" /> <img src="icons/iconmonstr-smartphone-3-120.png" alt="phone"> </label>
</div>
<form action="" id="tallyForm" onsubmit="return false;">
  <button class="accordion">
    <h2 class="float-left">2.</h2>
    <h2 class="text-center">Model</h2></button>
  <div class="panel" id="default_panel">
    <label>
      <h3 class="text-center">Please select a Device Type above</h3></label>
  </div>
  <div class="panel invisible" id="laptop_panel">
    <div id="col1">
      <label class="control control--radio">LAPTOP
        <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="laptop1" />
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div id="col3">
      <label class="control control--radio">LAPTOP2
        <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="laptop2" />
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
      <label class="control control--radio">LAPTOP3
        <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="laptop3" />
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel invisible" id="tablet_panel">
    <div id="col1">
      <label class="control control--radio">iPad 2
        <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="tablet-ipad2" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
      <label class="control control--radio">iPad 3
        <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="tablet-ipad3" onclick="calculateTotal()" />
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
      <label class="control control--radio">iPad 4
        <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="tablet-ipad4" />
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
      <label class="control control--radio">iPad Air
        <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="tablet-ipadAir" />
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
      <label class="control control--radio">iPad Mini
        <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="tablet-ipadMini" />
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
      <label class="control control--radio">iPad Mini 2
        <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="tablet-ipadMini2" />
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div id="col3">
      <label class="control control--radio">Nexus 7
        <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="tablet-nexus7" />
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
      <label class="control control--radio">Amazon Fire
        <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="tablet-amazonFire" />
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
      <label class="control control--radio">Amazon Kindle
        <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="tablet-amazonFire" />
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel invisible" id="phone_panel">
    <div id="col1">
      <label class="control control--radio">iPhone 3 &amp; 4
        <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="phone-iphone3" />
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
      <label class="control control--radio">iPhone 5, 5c, 5s
        <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="phone-iphone5cs" />
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
      <label class="control control--radio">iPhone 6
        <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="phone-iphone6" />
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
      <label class="control control--radio">iPhone 6 Plus
        <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="phone-iphone6+" />
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div id="col3">
      <label class="control control--radio">Microsoft Lumia 430
        <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="phone-lumia430" />
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div id="col2">
      <label class="control control--radio">Galaxy S3
        <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="phone-galaxys3" />
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
      <label class="control control--radio">Galaxy S4
        <input type="radio" name="radio-model" value="phone-galaxys4" />
        <div class="control__indicator"></div>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you sir you helped out a lot also sorry for taking so long to respond I stepped out of the house but how would I make model accordion toggle-able so collapsible